# Auto generate variable name and save to file in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, save

I have a Matlab application that generates a output matrix based on user input. I want to save it to a file or files. There are two ways I have in mind:

Multiple files; one matrix per file

```
user1.mat
user2.mat
....
```

Single file `allUser.mat` with multiple matrix

```
user1=[data1]
user1=[data2]
....
```

However I don't know how to keep track of the number, because every user will start a new instance of the application. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to simply edit (or create, if it's not there already) the `startup.m` file to ask the user for their user id, and then use that to load the correct file:

```
user_id = input("Enter your user id: ");
load(sprintf('user%i.mat', user_id));
```

Another way would be to use the unix `whoami` function, if each user uses their own logon:

```
[s,w]=unix('whoami');  %# w = eykanal
load(sprintf('%s_data.mat', w));
```